# what does it mean by utility first classes in css

Tags: css, tailwind-css, utility, tailwind-ui

I've started learning tailwind css and I read this (A utility-first CSS framework packed with classes) and that's not clear for me I don't understand what does it exactly mean by saying utility-first classes, what is utility-first classes in CSS ?

Comment: Utility first classes mean that you get the bare classes for most of your needs and you build components yourself using those classes. Tailwind doesn't enforce components on you. You use classes for example for laying out elements and build design yourself.

Comment: "Utility-first" means the framework's main focus is on providing utility classes. Utility classes are normally styles that do just one thing, add padding, add color etc. So you can combine them to create your own components. Same as what @Saqlain said, just giving my own take.